# DynamoDB schema with unknown PartitionKey

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I think that's a pretty straight-forward use-case for DynamoDB, but I couldn't think on a good solution.

Let's say I have a table like:

- OrderId
- PaymentId
- AmmountPaid

Sometimes I need to query by OrderId so I can get all the payments made for this Order.
Sometimes I need to know which order a paymentId is related to.

It seems to me it would make sense to have OrderId as the PartitionKey. The issue is that I won't know it when I'm querying based on PaymentId.

Is there a better solution than storing a map of PaymentId -> OrderId on another table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Secondary Indexes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html#GSI.Projections).

> Some applications might need to perform many kinds of queries, using a variety of different attributes as query criteria. To support these requirements, you can create one or more global secondary indexes and issue Query requests against these indexes. To illustrate, consider a table named GameScores that keeps track of users and scores for a mobile gaming application. Each item in GameScores is identified by a partition key (UserId) and a sort key (GameTitle). The following diagram shows how the items in the table would be organized. (Not all of the attributes are shown)